# How to retrieve an array of String[ ] from jsp to action with Struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I've some logic problem with Struts2, i'm trying to pass an array of Strings from jsp to an Action, the problem is that, when i try to pass this Strings in an ArrayList it goes well, i can see datas, when i try with the same names and values, to pass the value into a String[], the value it's just null, where i'm doing wrong?

That's my Action:

```
 public class EscludiElementoRicercaMagazzinoAction extends MyActionSupport {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7627908677897902673L;
    private static Logger                   logger              =           Logger.getLogger(EscludiElementoRicercaMagazzinoAction.class);
    String[] selezionato;



    public String[] getSelezionato() {
        return selezionato;
    }




    public void setSelezionato(String[] selezionato) {
        this.selezionato = selezionato;
    }



    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("inizio");
        //TODO DA FINIRE
        MovimentazioneMagazzino.escludiMagazzino(selezionato);
        logger.debug("fine");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And that's how i send data to action...

```
<input type="hidden" value="54" name="selezionato[0]" class="hiddenModaleEscludiElemento">
```

Comment: I'm asking to myself if there's some struts2 rule about this kind of thing that i dont know

Comment: If you show your code, It will be easy to understand what you are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the index in your input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="54" name="selezionato" class="hiddenModaleEscludiElemento">
```

Hope this would help.